# Is SpringSource the same thing as what Spring used to be before? :)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, spring-mvc

I last installed Spring a few years ago and back then it was just some jars I had to add.  Now after I googled for Spring, it brought me to SpringSource, a division of VMWare.

It took me through a whole installation process for the SpringSource Tool Suite and it looks cool, but is also bulky.

What are people doing for a robust and lightweight Java MVC framework these days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Spring MVC is a robust and lightweight Java MVC framework these days ;-)

One "problem", though: it uses Spring itself (of course), which has gotten much bigger over the years. What was once *just* a dependency injection framework, today is almost a complete Java EE replacement. Meaning: if you want Java EE without a true application server, then use Spring. And that boils down to using Tomcat with Spring in most cases.

So, the true answer is: you can still use Spring without much hassle, but use only what you need, if you really need it. Spring originates from 2003, when Java EE was a real pain in the neck, but nowadays Java EE has gotten more and more simple, almost to the point that it's preferred over Spring, especially EE 6.

Springsource Tools isn't needed for using Spring, but it is recommended for efficient Spring usage. If you stick with XML configuration, lack of tools assistance will hamper you in the long run.

My little rant is over, so I hope I helped you at least a bit.

Comment: Thanks! One question - when you say Java EE replaced Spring because it is so simple now, do you mean that somehow it is possible to get the dependency injection and MVC-ness from Java without Spring? And also, should I just go with it and use the Spring Tools?  What will happen when if I want to use other languages like Python or Ruby within the same project?  Is that going to be a pain to do?

Comment: Java EE 6 has standardized dependency injection. It's called context and dependency injection. Check out [JSR 299](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=299) and [JSR 330](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330) and Google them afterwards. As for MVC, you've got Java Server Faces 2 which is better and easier than previous versions and it integrates nicely with rest of Java EE. You don't need Spring Tools if you're not going to use Spring. You can use Python and Ruby by leveraging Jython and JRuby, although I haven't tried mixing all of them in one project and you shouldn't also unless you know why.

Comment: @ericacm: JSF is advertised as an MVC framework, although it is closer to being a component based framework. As far as I know, there is no pure standardized MVC framework for Java.

Answer (score 2):

Springsource Tool Suite is their customized distribution of Eclipse, and no you don't technically need it. You still only need the jar files, which can be found [here](http://www.springsource.org/download).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need SpringSource Tool Suite.

Spring is still the most popular lightweight Java MVC framework.

Spring is splitted into different modules (projects) to avoid big dependencies if you don't need them.

List of [projects](http://www.springsource.org/projects) from springsource

spring-framework-3.1.0.M1.zip is 25.6 MB and can be found [here](http://www.springsource.com/download/community)

Have fun!